# Contrast normalization issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to contrast normalize an image using openCV with the following code below. I tested the same code out in Matlab, and it works there. However, it doesn't in OpenCV. I threw in a bunch of checks in order to see if I was making a mistake somewhere, and I have a few questions.

**Background:** My image is an unsigned-char `CV_8U` image with dimensions `w640 x h480`. 
I convert the image to float `CV_32F` using the following line:

`img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 1.0f/255.0f);`

**Questions:**

1. I checked the value of the pixel present at `img.at<float>(25,25)`, and I saw a value which was greater than 3000.0f. Shouldn't the third argument in the `convertTo` function scale all pixel intensities between `[0.0 1.0]` in my image?
2. The idea I followed was similar to what I had done before in Matlab. The image there was of `uint` type ([0 255]), which when converted to double scaled the values between `[0 1]` and allowed me to apply the following code (in Matlab):

`cGN = (cG - min(cG(:))) ./ (max(cG(:)) - min(cG(:)));`

Here, I ignored the numerator in the first formula in this [wiki_Contrast_Norm_page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)), as I thought I already scaled my pixel values between `[0 1]`. I tried to take care while implementing the same formula in OpenCV, but I may be wrong somewhere?

**Code:**

```
if( img.type() != CV_8U ) {

    cout<<" before normalizing image, converting its type to CV_32F \n"<< endl;

    img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 1.0f/255.0f);
}

cout<<"inital access: " << img.at<float>(25,25)<<endl;

//float min_val_class = 0.0f; 
//float max_val_class = 1.0f; 

float min_val_im = 0.0f; 
float max_val_im = 0.0f; 

Mat mask = img > 0; 

for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; c++) { 
    for(int r = 0; r < img.rows; r++) { 

        if( mask.data[r*img.cols + c] != 0 ) { 

            float value = img.data[r*img.cols + c];

            if(value > max_val_im) { 
                max_val_im = value; 
            }       
            if(value < min_val_im) { 
                min_val_im = value; 
            }
        }
    }
}

float imDiff = max_val_im - min_val_im;

float diver = (1/imDiff); 

cout <<"min_val_im: " << min_val_im << endl; 

res = img.clone(); 

// now normalize the image 

cout<<"before sub: " << res.at<float>(25,25)<<endl;

subtract(res, min_val_im, res);

cout<<"after sub: " << res.at<float>(25,25)<<endl;

res = res.mul((diver)); 

cout<<"after mul: " << res.at<float>(25,25)<<endl;
```

Comment: float value = img.data[r*img.cols + c]; // this won't work. it's still a uchar. also, use minMaxLoc() instead of your loops

Comment: @berak I tried to use the `.at` method. That did not give me what I expected either. I will try the minMaxLoc() function.

Comment: Is `convertto` even being hit? Are you seeing the "normalizing image" message?

Comment: @beaker Shoot! It works now. You're right, it wasn't being taken because the condition was if `!=` to CV_8U, when it should have been `==`. Such a silly error. Thanks for pointing it out! Been staring at the code for too long that I missed such a small thing. :/

Comment: @Eagle We've all been there. ;)